# Unable to replace the special character(vbTab) in a string

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to replace the spaces in a string to underscores so that the file can be written with a name without any illegal characters exception .

Here is what I have tried:

```
Dim BuildAddr As String = "1050 N DAY MIAR RD   GRAND PRAIRIE   TX"
Dim lst As New List(Of String) _
    From {"vbTab", "/", "\", "^", "@"}

For Each Item As String In lst
    BuildAddr = BuildAddr.Replace(Item, " ")
Next

Return BuildAddr
```

The extra spaces in the above string are not normal spaces but vbTab. I am trying to replace that vbTab with single space and then I am replacing the single spaces with underscores like this:

```
BuildAddr = BuildAddr.Replace(" ", "_")
```

Could someone please provide any inputs on this, Thank You, have a nice day!!!

By the way I tried with Array too, and please ignore the spellings

Comment: Firstly, please don't post unformatted code snippets. This site provides a preview for a reason. Make sure your question is formatted properly before submitting.

Comment: *"The extra spaces in the above string are not normal spaces but vbTab"*. I don't think they are. As far as I'm are, it is impossible to represent a TAB character in a literal string in VB that way. In C# you can use `\t` but VB can't do that even. I suggest that you loop over characters in that string and check the Unicode point value of each one to see what they really are.

Comment: Hi jm, while debugging I noticed it contains vbTab in the string, we are not sure how we got that, it might be because of copy pasting from one source to the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"vbTab"` is the string composed of the characters {v, b, T, a, b}. You probably want the string given by the constant `vbTab`, i.e. without the double-quote marks around it.

However, you might find it tidier to use a [*regular expression*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) to do the replacement, for example:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim s = "ab\cd" & vbTab & "ef/gh@"
        Console.WriteLine(s)

        Dim re = New Regex("[\t\\/@]")
        s = re.Replace(s, " ")

        Console.WriteLine(s)

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

```
ab\cd   ef/gh@
ab cd ef gh
```

In a regex, `\` represents a [character escape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-escapes-in-regular-expressions), so `\t` stands for the tab character. To represent the escape character itself, `\\` is used. The square brackets surround a [character group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions), which represents any one of the characters inside.

Comment: Hey Andrew, Thanks for your response. I followed the same logic to overcome this issue and it worked out pretty well for me.